# Android adb debug blocked with APK signature verification failed

Tags: android, apk, adb

Building an app for Android Tv and when i want to use the debug on my tv or fire stick says it is not signed?but I have not finished the app yet..

tried a few adb steps to connect to tv but got unavailable device added my fire stick and it asked for RSA key but fails to launch due to app not signed?

no code needed

Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES
APK signature verification failed.
Retry

also registered my tv with the Google Cast SDK Developer Console paid the 5$.

Android studio 3.5

Answer (score 3):

Youll need to verify the minSdkVersion on the app build.gradle file whether its compatible with the device you are using

An example with minSdkVersion of 23 which represents android 6.0 the app cannot work on a device with android 5.1.
I faced the same issue when running the app on the emulator and found this to be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This problem started for me after upgrading the Gradle version from 3.4.2 to 3.5.0, available in the latest Android Studio update (3.5).

Try changing to 3.4.2 as a workaround.